# What does it mean by the phrase "map into"?

Tags: phrases

> [image]

What does it mean by the phrase "map into" in this context?

Does this phrase have any other meaning?

Comment: Generally, each element of *X* correlates with some location in the region *a*.

Comment: This seems to be a maths question rather than an English Language question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from mathematics.  Here, random variable *X* is viewed as a function which maps sample points (or states) into numbers.  And "maps" has the mathematical meaning: the action of a function.

Of course "maps" has other meanings in English, but do not use them to understand mathematics!

Comment: right person for the right question :D